# Loading multiple print statements in assembly

Tags: assembly, macros, armv8

So I’m new to assembly ARMV8 and was wondering, if I had multiple print statements like fmt1, fmt2, fmt3 and I wanted to print all them do I load them all into x0 register or do I need different registers to load them into ? So far only fmt1 is printing. The others aren’t.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Please clarify your question and show your code.  Assembly language doesn't have "print statements", only instructions and directives.  Maybe you are making a call to a library function such as `printf` but without seeing your code it's hard to guess what you mean.